# Swift inherited classes

Tags: class, inheritance, swift

What the different between the following var declared (in Swift)

```
var taskMgr = TaskManager()
```

and

```
var taskMgr:TaskManager = TaskManager()
```

So far It compiled and worked.

```
    import UIKit

    var taskMgr = TaskManager()

    struct task{
        var name = "Un-Named"
        var desc = "Un-Desc"
        }

    // Inherited class from NSObject
    class TaskManager: NSObject {
        var tasks = [task]()
        func addTask(name: String, desc: String){
            tasks.append(task(name: name, desc: desc))
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initiate variable there is no difference between `taskMgr` and `taskMgr:TaskManager`. Swift compiler should know about `taskMgr` type.

However if you define optional variable, you must tell to compiler what type you expected. For example:

```
var taskMgr:TaskManager?
```

Or if you want to *force* type definition to override default type. For example with inherited classes. Consider following:

```
class ParentClass: NSObject {
    func parentFoo() ->String{
        return "I'm parent method"
    }
}


class ChildClass: ParentClass {
    func childFoo() ->String{
        return "I'm child method"
    }
}

var child = ChildClass() // child has type of ChildClass

println(child.childFoo()) // out: "I'm child method"
println(child.parentFoo())// out: "I'm parent method"

var parentOnly:ParentClass = ChildClass() // <-- force type

println(parentOnly.childFoo()) // ERROR: ParentClass does not have childFoo() method
println(parentOnly.parentFoo()) // out: "I'm parent method"
```

Comment: Thanks and what its mean by "if define optional variable"

Comment: @user3528013 " optional variable"means that you create variable with `nil` value and you are not sure if this variable will be initialized in the future.

Comment: ++@drewag Thanks and Hi all. Forgive me I am Swift newbie.

Comment: I like to extend to the next question: Why I can not inherit those classes to a new class e.g.: class PeopleClass: ParentClass, ChildClass { // error: Multiple inheritance from class PeopleClass and ParentClass
    
} Just like class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate { // This one no error}

Comment: @user3528013 because ChildClass inherits ParentClass so for  PeopleClass enough to inherit  ChildClass

Comment: I simulated new independent classes still error. I moved my extend multiple inherit classes error to open new question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Both version are doing the exact same thing. To understand that, you have to understand that Swift has a feature called [Type Inference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_473). This means that the compiler can figure out the type of a variable based on the initial value it is given.

The second version you declared is the full and deliberate version:

```
var taskMgr:TaskManager = TaskManager()
```

With this you are creating a variable of type `TaskManager` and assigning a new task manager to it.

The first version is the shorter version that uses Type Inference:

```
var taskMgr = TaskManager()
```

With this you are not explicitly giving `taskMgr` a type. You don't need to declare the type because you are already assigning it to a value of type `TaskManager`. The compiler can figure the type out automatically.

You only actually need to specify a type when you need the type to be something different than the compiler will infer from the initial value you are giving it. For example, if you need to make a variable optional or you need a variable to be the type of a superclass of the value you are assigning it.